# For Loop with nested Forfiles only works if batch is in same folder

Tags: batch-file

My code works fine when I have the *.bat* in the "*%USERPROFILE%\Downloads*" folder which is where I want it to look for *.zip* files. I just can't work out how to point here if the *.bat* lives elsewhere. If I move the *.bat* to another location there is no output, the file doesn't appear to do anything.

I have tried adding the following before the [FOR] command but this doesn't seem to help. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
CD %USERPROFILE%\Downloads
```

Here is my code...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (EPSG*.zip) do (
 for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%K in ('
  forfiles /p "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" /m "%%~F" /c "cmd /c echo @FDATE^|@FTIME"
    ') do (
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
     set "name=%%~F"
     set "timestamp=%%~K %%L"
     set "timestamp=!timestamp:/=-!"
     set "timestamp=!timestamp::=.!"
     set "destpath=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Nearmap Downloads\!timestamp!"
     powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force -Path '!name!' -DestinationPath '!destpath!'"
     endlocal
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Why are you using `forfiles` to get the date/time-stamp? you could also immediately use [`%%~tF`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) from the outer [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to get it...

Comment: I only used the forfiles loop because I need to get the last modified file time with _seconds_. `%%~tF` only outputs _hours_ and _minutes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "rootdir=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"

for %%F in ("%rootdir%\EPSG*.zip") do (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%K in ('
     forfiles /p "%rootdir%" /m "%%~nxF" /c "cmd /c echo @FDATE^|@FTIME"
    ') do (
        set "name=%%~F"
        set "timestamp=%%~K %%L"

        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "timestamp=!timestamp:/=-!"
        set "timestamp=!timestamp::=.!"
        set "destpath=!rootdir!\Nearmap Downloads\!timestamp!"
        powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Force -Path '!name!' -DestinationPath '!destpath!'"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

- The basic `for` loop changed to use a full path.
- The `forfiles` uses a searchmask of the current
  zip filename by using `for` modifiers of `nx`.
- Set `rootdir` to store the root directory to
  avoid some duplication, so that change of root
  directory can be changed in the 1 `set` value.
- `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` moved to where
  needed and not before.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
PUSHD "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
...
)
POPD
pause
```

Once a `PUSHD` instruction is executed, the argument becomes the current directory (so you need not include it in the `forfiles` line...) until the matching `POPD` is executed, restoring the original current-directory.

And then if *yourbatch.bat* is placed in any directory on the **PATH** you should be able to execute it by simply typing *yourbatch* at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've added a nested `for` loop containing the resource intensive `forfiles` command, you should be able to do it more like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "sourcepath=%UserProfile%\Downloads"
Set "destpath=%sourcepath%\Nearmap Downloads"
For %%A In ("%sourcepath%\EPSG*.zip")Do (Set "timestamp=%%~tA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "timestamp=!timestamp:/=-!"
    Powershell -NoProfile -Command "Expand-Archive -Force -Path '%%A' -DestinationPath '%destpath%\!timestamp::=.!'"
    EndLocal)
```

*As you're running the a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script anyhow, I'm a little baffled why you didn't do it all within the same `.ps1` script!*

Comment: I only used the `forfiles` loop because I need to get the last modified file time with seconds.

Comment: @RDunkley, well had you just done the entire thing in [tag:powershell], it would be more efficient and you could have got the timestamp like this: `"$destpath\$(($zipfile.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss"))"`

Comment: Thanks @Compo, Learning powershell is on my to-do list..! I am still more comfortable with batch. This particular _.bat_ is also being called from a _lisp_ routine in Autocad. Regards.